# Removing the content of a li from a list and delete the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grails

I'm trying to use a button to make a li disappear from a page, but the content of the li is a string that is in a list called additional-text-list, and the code for the li itself is in another list called textList. The code for filling up textList is here:

```
$('#append').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#new-text').val();
    var bullet = '<li>' + text +  'input type="hidden" name="additionalList" value="'+text+'"/> </li>';
    $('#additional-text-list').append(li);
    $('#new-text').val('');
});
```

The page renders every 'bullet' as individual lines of code, creating a series of bulleted items, but it also adds the input text into a list called additionalList. I want the li to go away and the text to be removed from additionalList whenever the button is clicked. Right now I'm focusing on the former goal, and this is what I have:

```
$('#removeText').on('click', 'li>.remove-btn', function (event){
//$(event.currentTarget).closest('li').remove();
$(this).closest.('li').remove();  
});
```

The line of code that's noted out is some code I tried out previously but did not work.
This is the html code for rendering the lis:

```
<div class="row">
            <ul id ="additional-text-list"> 
        <!-- this ul is where we render the text -->
                <g:each var="additionalList" in="${userInstance.additionalList*.text}">
                    <li class ="text-list-item">
                     <button type="button" title="Remove Text">

                     <i class="fa fa-close" id = "removeText"></i>  </button>
                        ${additionalText} 
                        <input type="hidden" name="additionalText" value="${additionalText}"/>

                    </li>
                </g:each>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Right now I'm not on my usual computer, so please ignore any typos in the html; that I know works perfectly. Does anybody have any advice on how to remove the text?

Comment: can you show your `HTML` ?

Comment: I think this line should be: `var bullet = <li' + text + '<input type="hidden" name="additionalList" value="'+text+'"> </li>;`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the delete button is inside the `li`?

Then do this:

```
$(this).parents('li:eq(0)');
```

That will search for the first parent element `li` for the clicked element in your case.

Comment: If the button or click element is inside the `li` it should work, what does your browser console say?